# how to capture a block in a helper's child class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capture, view-helpers

I'm trying to do the following:

```
module ApplicationHelper

   class PModuleHelper
     include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
     def heading(head = "", &block)
       content = block_given? ? capture(&block) : head.to_s
       content_tag :h3, content, :class => :module_header
     end
   end

    def getmh
        PModuleHelper.new
    end

end
```

Either give a string (or symbol) to the method `heading`, or a block.

In View:

```
<% mh = getmh %>
<%= mh.heading :bla %> // WORKS
<%= mh.heading do %>   // FAILS
    test 123
<% end %>
```

(note the `getmh` is just for this example, the `PModuleHelper` is returned by some other process in my application, so no need to comment on this or suggest to make `heading` a normal helper method, not a class-method)

Unfortunately I always get the following error:

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

with linenumber for the `capture(&block)` call.

How to use `capture` inside own helper class?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd do something like this :

```
module Applicationhelper
  class PModuleHelper

    attr_accessor :parent

    def initialize(parent)
      self.parent = parent
    end

    delegate :capture, :content_tag, :to => :parent

    def heading(head = "", &block)
      content = block_given? ? capture(&block) : head.to_s
      content_tag :h3, content, :class => :module_header
    end
  end

  def getmh
    PModuleHelper.new(self)
  end
end
```

I can't guarantee this will work, because I had this error : `undefined method 'output_buffer='` instead of the one you're mentioning. I haven't been able to reproduce yours.

Comment: that nearly does it! One error, though: `content_tag` must be delegated, too (in my original question I updated I included the helpers, now)! Then everything works. And seems to be very logical, why it does!

Comment: would look more the rails way with `delegate :capture, :content_tag, :to => :parent` ;-)